# Is the TIN created out of several cross sections different from merging the TINs created out of each set of two cross sections?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, topology, tin

I have a river with cross sections that have the water surface elevation values. I am trying to create TIN from the water surface values and then compare it with the topo (to see the flooded areas). I wonder what would be the difference between the TIN created out of several cross sections is different from merging the TINs created out of each set of two cross sections? Does the TIN creation process includes any sort of generalization/ approximation/ getting average when it comes to several features or it is dependent on the adjacent features only? 
My tests on the river shows no distinct difference between the resulting floodplain but I am not quite sure it is the same everywhere. Any thought? 
[image]